# ReactJS: Get key from array of objects inside map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I have below code. I am able to get the values. I want to get keys. How can I get that?

```
    var labelIndex = 0;
    const labelArr = [
        "Name", "IP Address", "Port", "SSH User", "SSH Port", "License"
    ];        

    const state = [
        {name: "abc", ipaddr: "192.168.1.2", port: 5000},
        {sshuser: "xyz", sshport: 21, license: "license.txt"}
    ];

    {state.map((item, index1) => (
    <tr key={index1}>
    {Object.values(item).map((val,index2) => (
        <td key={labelIndex++}>
            <b>{labelArr[labelIndex]}</b><br/>
            <input required 
            type="text"
            id={labelIndex}
            name={labelIndex}
            onChange={(e) => {}}
            value={val}/>
        </td>
    ))}
    </tr>
))}
```

As you can see I am using labelIndex for name and id as below.

```
        id={labelIndex}
        name={labelIndex}
```

I want to use corresponding key as name and id like as below.

```
        id=ipaddr
        name=ipaddr
```

Please let me know how I can get the key inside map().

Comment: What relations are there between `state` and `labelArr`? Fields in state are different from `labelArr`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: what about Object.entries
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: @Adrid, no relation as such. I am showing the data in a table to user in a proper format (for me 3 input fields in one line). So the array of 1 object having six members want to break into array of 2 objects each having 3 member.

Comment: @jsejcksn, it may be helpful. However for me the key part was "Object.keys(item)" which I did not know previously.

Comment: @kag, I am using map() here and my interest was to get key/value pair.